# std::distance "no matching overloaded function found"

Tags: c++, templates, iterator, std

I'm trying to implement a sequence-based constructor that gets 2 forward iterators that define a range [first, last), and do something with them.
Problem is I need the distance between them and for some reason I'm getting this error:
`'std::distance': no matching overloaded function found`:

```
template<class Itr>
SmartStack(Itr first, Itr last)
{
    auto range = std::distance<Itr>(first, last);
    ...
}
```

Edit:
Apparently this constructor conflicts when calling `SmartStack<int> s(2, 0);` in my main:

And the other constructor is:

```
SmartStack(size_t size, const T& v) : SmartStack()
{
    ...
}
```

What can I do to prevent it? I only want the first ctr to be called whenever the input is an iterator..

Thanks!

Comment: Since this is an error with a template, it's helpful to see more of the error message. Can you show us the full compiler error and any code beyond what's here that's referenced?

Comment: Thanks! By looking at the compiler error I understand now why it's happening, but how can I fix it? Look at the edited question- I hope that's enough code.

Comment: `SmartStack` needs an iterator you are trying to instantiate it with `int` as in `SmartStack<int>` an `int` is not an iterator.  Without knowing what you intend it's hard to suggest a fix; see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance

Comment: I'll try to explain. I want `SmartStack<int> s(2, 0)` to call the constructor `SmartStack(size_t size, const T& v)`. But instead it calls `SmartStack(Itr first, Itr last)` even though it need iterators. So I don't understand why is the iterator constructor is called?

Comment: please show a [mre]. There is nothing to restrict `Itr` to being an iterator type so it will accept any type, I guess your iterator constructor is simply a better match for the arguments than your other constructor

Comment: Your `(Itr first, Itr last)` constructor doesn't say "I want two iterators." It says "I want two parameters that are the same type." And `2` and `0` are the same type (integers). You need to refine the constructor so it says "I want two parameters that are the same type **and that type must be an iterator that supports difference**": `template<typename Itr, typename = typename std::iterator_traits<Itr>::difference_type> SmartStack(Itr first, Itr last)`

Comment: Thanks! Just what I needed!